# What does SharePoint date-time field contain by default?

Tags: list, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-fields

If you add an item in a list containing date-time field but to leave the date blank what will that column contain? Is it null,or empty string or something else?

**Update**

I have tried to create a workflow and set a workflow variable to that date field and log it to the workflow history but i get following outcome

[image]

[image]

If this is the case then how to check if a date-time field is empty or not in workflow?

Answer (score 1):

To check if a date-time field is empty or not just create a workflow variable of type Date-time call it say "Empty" and than in the if condition check with this variable

Answer (score -1):

The default value (default constraint in SQL Server) is stored in the database only when the column is not specified in an INSERT statement.  If datetime2 value '001-01-01 00:00:00' is being stored, that means the application is including the datetime2 column in the insert statement and passing either an empty string or a DateTime instance without an assigned value.

May be you need something like in [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cd1f9ae5-9edb-4b66-b3fa-8fbdb1dc6cb9/email-from-workflow-contains-110001-120000-am-for-items-empty-date-field?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious) solution - check for equality with '01.01.0001 5:30:00'